# Custom properties in SVN & retrive files based on the property

Tags: svn, properties, tortoisesvn

is it possible to add a Custom Property for my files in SVN?

e.g. I want to add an entry "Release Ref:" which can be list like 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.31, 3.4 ..etc.

Second I want to get all the files from the Branch based on this property entry!

is that possible from CLI or ANT?

I am a little new to SVN Please help

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can [add any custom property you like](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.html):

> Generally speaking, the names and values of the properties can be
>   whatever you want them to be, with the constraint that the names must
>   contain only ASCII characters.

To search for files based on properties, use [svn propget](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.propget.html):

```
svn propget prefix:prop-name -R
```